# MATLAB version of python iterator

Tags: python, matlab, graphics

I need to specify the color and marker for a series of plots on the same axis. In Python, I would simply create an iterator for each and use `next()` to get them out in order one at a time. I cannot find an equivalent in MATLAB; all the examples I have found involve explicitly calling the list holding the colors and markers by index, but this precludes using them in loops that don't use a matching iterator. Is there a more appropriate substitution for the iterator concept?

Alternately, is there a more appropriate way to accomplish this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ColorOrder`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#prop_ColorOrder) and [`LineStyleOrder`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#prop_LineStyleOrder) properties of the axis: you can find [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/defining-the-color-of-lines-for-plotting.html) the complete documentation.

The `ColorOrder` property is a three-column matrix of RGB triplets and the `LineStyleOrder` is a cell array of line specifiers or, alternatively, a string of specifiers separated by `|`.

[image: Example usage of ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder properties]

This figure has been created using the code below. Of course, you can also generate the `ColorOrder` matrix using one of the [built-in colormaps](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#inputarg_map) or even a custom one.

```
figure;

set(gca, 'ColorOrder', hsv(5));
set(gca, 'LineStyleOrder', '-|--|:');

hold on;

t = 0:pi/20:2*pi;
for i = 1:15
    plot(t, sin(t-i/5));
end
```

Anyway, as far as I know in MATLAB there isn't the concept of iterator, especially in the Python sense, but at least this solution should address your problem without explicitly calling the list of colors and/or marker by index.

Comment: I need to change the marker, not the line style. This is a series of point plots, not line plots. I need 1 diamond, then circle, then square, etc.

Comment: @Elliot Then change the `LineStyleOrder` property accordingly: `set(gca, 'LineStyleOrder', 'd|o|s')` without solid line or `set(gca, 'LineStyleOrder', '-d|-o|-s')` with solid line. The format specification defines both the LineStyle and the Marker.

Comment: If I use `set(gca, 'NextPlot', 'replacechildren');` it only shows the last item. The color updates when I use the above code without that line, but the line style is stuck always using the second item.

Comment: Indeed that line was not necessary, because `hold on` is basically a shortcut for `set(gca, 'NextPlot', 'add')`. I've removed it from the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the look (such as color and marker) for the plots in the plot command. E.g. `plot(1:5,'-go')` will produce a green plot with `o`-makers.([Info](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-high-level-plotting-functions.html))

---

Alternatively, you can indeed iterate over the plots in an axis. If you do all the plots in one command, like

```
h = plot(1:5,[1:5;2:2:10]);
```

then `h` will be a vector of chart line objects, and you can then iterate over these objects using

```
for i=1:length(h)
    h(i).<some_modifications>
end
```

and set properties like this:

```
h(i).LineWidth = 2;
h(i).Marker = '*';
```

or in MATLAB versions before 2014:

```
set(h(i),'LineWidth',2)
set(h(i),'Marker','*')
```

If you do the plots in separate commands, you can manually collect the returned chart line objects in a vector and do the same thing (or of course modify them directly). You can find some properties you can use [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html).

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I assumed you are doing line plots. If you use `mesh`, `area`, ... to create area/surface plots, there are some more options.